# jpa - oracle - too many database link - ORA-02020

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have a `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`it's looks like this way:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "addLongDesc", resultClasses=Integer.class, procedureName = "myProc", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "b_cus_id", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "b_case_id", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "b_user_id", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "v_customerno", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "v_tickler_id", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "v_calleruser", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "v_megalltext", type = String.class)
    })
})
```

I'm trying to call the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` this way:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public boolean changeLongDesc(KallerMainFormParam formObj, String longDesc) {

    Integer result = 0;

    try {
    result = (Integer) em.createNamedQuery("addLongDesc")
                    .setParameter("b_cus_id", formObj.getKallerCusInstance().getId().toString())
                    .setParameter("b_case_id", formObj.getKallerCaseInstance().getId().toString())
                    .setParameter("b_user_id", formObj.getKallerUsr().getId().toString())
                    .setParameter("v_customerno", formObj.getKallerCusInstance().getCustomerno())
                    .setParameter("v_tickler_id", formObj.getKallerCaseInstance().getBKallerCaseData().getTicklerId().toString())
                    .setParameter("v_calleruser", formObj.getKallerUsr().getJazzUser())
                    .setParameter("v_megalltext", "B - " + longDesc).getSingleResult();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.warning(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return result != 0;

}
```

The procedure in the oracle database looks like this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure myProc (b_cus_id number , b_case_id number, b_user_id number, v_customerno varchar2, v_tickler_id number, v_calleruser varchar2, v_megalltext varchar2)
as
result number;
begin
result := remoteDbProc@DBLINK(v_tickler_id , v_megalltext, v_calleruser);
insert into b_Tickler_Access_Log VALUES (B_CASE_TICKLER_SEQ.nextval, v_customerno, b_cus_id, b_case_id,b_user_id,v_tickler_id, 'LONG_DESC', v_jazz_result, sysdate);    
end;
```

Everything works fine, if there is little numbers of request. But if the users starts to work with the application and the request's numbers getting more and more, i got Internal database exception bacause of ORA-02020 – Too many database links in use error.

I tried to add this line to the end of my stored procedure: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK DBLINK';`

But it wasn't help.

Unfortunately I can't set the INIT.ORA open_links maximum parameter, and i can't ask the DBA neither.

Can anybody please tell me any advice how to solve this problem without DBA settings?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK DBLINK';` doesn't help, so I can only speculate.

You can't close the DB LINK if the session is not commited.

Here some hints for troubleshooting

The open links  for your session are visible in

```
select db_link, in_transaction from V$DBLINK;
```

Please note also, that while using DB LINK you open a transaction even with a SELECT (you don't need update).

```
DEMO    NO
DEMO2   YES
```

You may need priviledge

```
grant select on V_$DBLINK to your_user;
```

to access this view (I know this needs DBA, but simple risk the request:)

So in the example above you may close the db link DEMO, but not the DEMO2.

Trying to do so, you get `ORA-02080:  "database link is in use"`and the link remains open.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned above a DB LINK session can't be closed while the transaction is open, so the simplest possible way to close the DB LINK after the call of the remote procedure (actually is is a function) is a explicit commit.

This could be somehow as follows (I use simplified version of you procedure)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure myProc (id number )
as
result number;
begin
result := remoteDbFun@DEMO(1);
-- add this to close transaction and close DB link
commit;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK DEMO';
--
insert into Access_Log VALUES (result, sysdate);    
end;
/
```

A big drawback of this approach is that you ends the transaction - which will probably conflict with your transaction control. So you may use [autonomous transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm) to avoid it.

This is done with a sub-function defined with autonomous transaction that calls the  remote function, makes the COMMIT (but autonomous i.e. not visible to the main session) and close the DB LINK.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function myFun (id number ) return NUMBER as
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

result number;
begin
result := remoteDbFun@DEMO(1);
commit;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK demo';
return result;
end;
/
```

Your PROCEDURE myProc calls instead of the remote function this new function.
It is guarantied that after the call no DB LINK is open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I tried  to put EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK command at the first line of the stored procedure then when I try to execute the proc it says there is no open dblink.. And couldn't execute. If I put the command to the end of the proc the same error occurred. There is no chance to get privilege to select on V$DBLINK :(

Comment: @solarenqu [OPEN_LINKS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams139.htm#REFRN10138) specifies the maximum number of concurrent open connections to remote databases in **one session**. So I don't see a problem with increased numer od sessions. I assume you use more different DB links that the parameter value - **this should be adjusted**. Anyway I updatetd the answer with a workaround.

Comment: it gives this error,  ORA-00164: distributed autonomous transaction disallowed within migratable distributed transaction. It means oracle not allow to use db link in autonomous transactions. so it fails :(